# Bind Database Values To RadiobuttonList In Mvc Without Using Foreach Loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi am facing problem to bind collection values to radiobuttonlist without using for loop.
lets consider below model

```
public class EducationList
    {
       //Some Fields
        public ICollection<CourseTypes> employee_CourseTypes { get; set; }
    }
```

course type contains Cource name and cource id
i need to bind these cource types to radiobutton list in mvc 
without using for loop

i have declared to get cource type method called getcources in some class i=this method returns courcename and cource id

just comapare below code

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CourceId, new SelectList(Model.employee_CourseTypes, "CourceTypeTypeId", "CourceName"), "--Select--")
```

like this i have to bind radiobuttonlist please help and your help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Write your own custom html helper! And in any case your model needs a property to bind to.

Comment: I dont have any idea about custom helper ..please post links custom helper regarding radiobuttonlist

Comment: AKAIK, there are none for a `Radiobuttonlist` - you going to have to do this yourself. But what's wrong with using a loop to generate the radio buttons - its just 3 lines of code?

Comment: but it is easy to have one line code and flexible so

Comment: Well here is the [source code for DropDownList](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/SelectExtensions.cs) to help you get started. Good luck.